# Leaflet dictionary and if

Tags: dictionary, if-statement, colors, leaflet

Please how to use dictionary to color city with leaflet? I tried this solution  in my html file but it didn't work.

```
zone0 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'R', 'S', 'T'];
zoneI = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'K', 'V', 'Z'];
zoneIII = ['H', 'I', 'M', 'N', 'L'];
```

```
  var commune = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'ville' %}", {

    style: function colors(feature){
      if (feature.properties.name) in zone0 {
          return{
            color: 'red',
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          };
          }

      if (feature.properties.name) in zoneI {
        return{
          color: 'purple',
          fillOpacity: 0.8
          };          break;
      }
      if (feature.properties.name) in zoneIII {
        return{
          color: 'green',
          fillOpacity: 0.8
          };
      }
          

      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
          var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Ville</th><td>" + feature.properties.name + "<table>";
            layer.on({
              click: function (e) {
                layer.bindPopup(content).openPopup(e.latlng);
              }
          });
        }
      
        //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString());
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share a geojson sample

Comment: At first sight that seems like a trivial JS syntax error - instead of `if (feature.properties.name) in zone0 {` it should be `if (feature.properties.name in zone0) {` with the whole comparison expression inside parentheses. Do check your browser console for errors before jumping to stackoverflow. Also, the `in` operator in JS doesn't work as you are expecting; do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Just to clarify: you are using _arrays_, not _dictionaries_ (which are plain objects in JS).

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.indexOf(name) > -1` instead of the the keyword `in`:

```
if (zoneIII.indexOf(feature.properties.name) > -1) {
```

indexOf returns the index of the found element, if no element is found it returns -1.

Comment: it still doesn't work. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Please share a sample of your geojson with the properties